# ReactJS – if value is undefined, display placeholder image

Tags: reactjs

0

I am creating a find nearest restaurant app using Google Places API. I am calling for a background image in my ResultItem component in a prop `<ResultsItem name={places.name} image={Thumbnail} rating={places.rating} rating_total={places.user_ratings_total} />`

This image is defined as Thumbnail in const above this part of the code. My code runs smoothly but as soon as places.photos[0] returns as undefined (meaning that it is Google Place that doesn't have any image uploaded) i get an error saying:

Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property '0' of undefined

I think what I have to do is check whether places.photos[0] is undefined or not but I do not seem to get it right...

My goal is to display another placeholder image when this value turns out undefined. If it is defined though the component should take the image from google places api.

This is what I have tried to do with the const Thumbnail to achieve it, but didnt work:

```
const Thumbnail =
          places && places.photos[0]
            ? `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=${places.photos[0].photo_reference}&key=MYAPIKEY`
            : 'https://www.xy.com/images/placeholder.jpg';
```

Can someone help me?

FULL COMPONENT:

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';

// Imports
import axios from 'axios';
import Script from 'react-load-script';
import Placeholder from './Placeholder.jsx';
import FadeIn from 'react-fade-in';
import {
  Spinner,
  Paragraph,
  SideSheet,
  Tooltip,
  IconButton,
  SearchInput
} from 'evergreen-ui';
import ResultsItem from '../../components/ResultsItem/ResultsItem.jsx';

import Geocode from 'react-geocode';

// Styles
import './Search.scss';

class Autocomplete extends Component {
  // Define Constructor
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Declare State
    this.state = {
      type: 'restaurant',
      radius: 10,
      lat: '59.0738',
      lng: '41.3226',
      city: '',
      query: '',
      open: false,
      places: [],
      place_detail: [],
      sidebar: false,
      loading: true
    };

    this.currentLocationOnClick = this.currentLocationOnClick.bind(this);
    this.handlePlaceSelect = this.handlePlaceSelect.bind(this);
  }

  currentLocationOnClick = async () => {
    let { lat, lng, places } = this.state;
    const URL = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=${lat},${lng}&type=restaurant&radius=${5 *
      1000}&key=MY_API_KEY`;
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      async position => {
        this.setState({ lat: position.coords.latitude });
        this.setState({ lng: position.coords.longitude });

        const URL = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=${
          position.coords.latitude
        },${position.coords.longitude}&type=restaurant&radius=${5 *
          1000}&key=MY_API_KEY`;

        const response = await axios.get(URL);
        console.log(response.data);
        places = response.data.results;
        this.setState({ places });
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Error getting location');
      }
    );
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=
    ${this.state.lat},${this.state.lng}type=restaurant&radius=${2 *
      1000}&key=MY_API_KEYE`;
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ places: data.results });
    console.log(data.results);
  }

  handleScriptLoad = () => {
    // Declare Options For Autocomplete
    const options = {
      types: ['address']
    }; // To disable any eslint 'google not defined' errors

    // Initialize Google Autocomplete
    /*global google*/ this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      document.getElementById('autocomplete'),
      options
    );

    // Avoid paying for data that you don't need by restricting the set of
    // place fields that are returned to just the address components and formatted
    // address.
    this.autocomplete.setFields(['address_components', 'formatted_address']);

    // Fire Event when a suggested name is selected
    this.autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', this.handlePlaceSelect);
  };

  handlePlaceSelect = async () => {
    let { query, lat, lng } = this.state;

    this.setState({ loading: true });

    // Extract City From Address Object
    const addressObject = this.autocomplete.getPlace();
    const address = addressObject.address_components;

    Geocode.setApiKey('MY_API_KEY');

    // Check if address is valid
    let city;
    if (address) {
      city = address[0].long_name;
      query = addressObject.formatted_address;
    }

    try {
      const response = await Geocode.fromAddress(query);
      ({ lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }

    let places;
    try {
      const URL = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=${lat},${lng}&type=restaurant&radius=${5 *
        1000}&key=MY_API_KEY`;
      const response = await axios.get(URL);
      console.log(response.data);
      places = response.data.results;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }

    this.setState({ query, places, city, lat, lng });
    setTimeout(() => this.setState({ loading: false }), 400);
  };

  render() {
    const { loading } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="flex align-center">
          <div className="search">
            <SearchInput
              id="autocomplete"
              placeholder="Search by address"
              width="100%"
              height={56}
            />
            <Script
              url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&libraries=places,geometry&callback=initAutocomplete"
              onLoad={this.handleScriptLoad}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="current-location">
            <Tooltip content="Use current location">
              <IconButton
                icon="locate"
                iconSize={16}
                height={32}
                onClick={this.currentLocationOnClick}
              >
                {this.state.lat} & {this.state.lng}
              </IconButton>
            </Tooltip>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="results">
          {this.state.places.map(places => {
            const Thumbnail = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=${places.photos[0].photo_reference}&key=MY_API_KEY
    `;
            return (
              <div
                className="results-flex"
                onClick={async () => {
                  let loading;
                  let sidebar;
                  let place_detail;
                  try {
                    const URL = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=${places.place_id}&fields=name,rating,formatted_phone_number&key=
                    MY_API_KEY`;
                    const response = await axios.get(URL);
                    console.log(response.data);
                    place_detail = response.data.result;
                  } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error.message);
                  }

                  this.setState(
                    { place_detail, sidebar: true }
                    // () => this.props.sideBarOpen()
                  );
                }}
              >
                {this.state.loading ? (
                  <>
                    <div className="flex justify-center">
                      <Placeholder />
                    </div>
                  </>
                ) : (
                  <FadeIn>
                    <ResultsItem
                      name={places.name}
                      image={Thumbnail}
                      rating={places.rating}
                      rating_total={places.user_ratings_total}
                    />
                  </FadeIn>
                )}
              </div>
            );
          })}

          <SideSheet
            isShown={this.state.sidebar}
            onCloseComplete={() => this.setState({ sidebar: false })}
          >
            <Paragraph margin={40}>{this.state.place_detail.name}</Paragraph>
          </SideSheet>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Autocomplete;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be arising beacuse when a Google Place doesn't have any image uploaded then there is not any element pointing to "places.photos[0]" which results in error: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.
So in const Thumbnail u must also check whether places.photos array exist or not.
I hope the below code solves your issue.

```
 const Thumbnail =
      places && places.photos && places.photos[0]
        ? `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=${places.photos[0].photo_reference}&key=MYAPIKEY`
        : 'https://www.xy.com/images/placeholder.jpg';
```

Comment: Hi Thanks! I dont get the error anymore... The problem now is that the placeholder image doesnt seem to be display instead of the default google placeholder. What i get is the google places api default placholder which i do not want to display. i want to display the one from the placholder link for example as you have in the end of the code you proposed now.

Comment: For that you need to share the placeholder code so that I can find out the exact problem.

Comment: The placeholdee is supposed to be only url going to png image - it’s supposed to be this part - https://www.xy.com/images/placeholder.jpg